# How to call a stored JavaScript function to add a field to objects returned by a query using linq and c# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, stored-functions

I have this query:

```
var professionalProfilesQuery = 
    (from profileCollection in _mongoContext.Database.GetCollection<Profile>("profiles").AsQueryable()
     join userCollection in _mongoContext.Database.GetCollection<User>("users").AsQueryable()
     on profileCollection.UserId equals userCollection.Id.Value
     into users
     orderby profileCollection.Name
     select new ProfessionalProfile
     {
         Id = profileCollection.Id,
         Name = profileCollection.Name,                                                 
         UserId = profileCollection.UserId,
         IsConfirmed = users.First().IsConfirmed,                                                 
     })
     .Where(p => p.IsConfirmed);
```

And then I have a stored javascript function in DB that calculates a "Score" for each `ProfessionalProfile` according to data in several collections (I need to sort results later according to that score). Something like:

```
function candidateScore(objectWithDataToCalculateScore, professionalProfile) {

    var score = 0;
    //Calculate score here
    return score;
}
```

Is it possible to add a field to data returned by the query with the calculated score? How can I call the stored javascript function to do so? I'd like to do something like:

```
var professionalProfilesQuery = 
    (from profileCollection in _mongoContext.Database.GetCollection<Profile>("profiles").AsQueryable()
     join userCollection in _mongoContext.Database.GetCollection<User>("users").AsQueryable()
     on profileCollection.UserId equals userCollection.Id.Value
     into users
     orderby profileCollection.Name
     select new ProfessionalProfile
     {
         Id = profileCollection.Id,
         Name = profileCollection.Name,                                                 
         UserId = profileCollection.UserId,
         IsConfirmed = users.First().IsConfirmed,   
         Score = ***CallToCandidateScoreFunctionHere...***                                     
     })
     .Where(p => p.IsConfirmed);
```

If that's not possible or it's not a good way to do it, would you suggest another approach instead of stored javascript function?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** After reading comments from Neil Lunn, I'll explain better the calculation I need.

This is an example of the class that models the collection that would be the first parameter in the previous `candidateScore` javascript function:

```
public class ProfessionalProfileRequirements
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> LanguagesRequired { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SkillsRequired { get; set; }
}
```

And this the javascript function again with some of the calculations (it's quite complex, so I simplified it. I hope it's enough to show what I need):

```
function candidateScore(professionalProfileRequirements, professionalProfile) {                         
    var score = 0;

    if (professionalProfileRequirements.Province === professionalProfile.Province)  {
        score += 1000;
    }

    if (professionalProfileRequirements.Role && professionalProfile.Roles && professionalProfile.ExperienceLevel){
        if (professionalProfile.Roles.includes(professionalProfileRequirements.Role)) {
            switch (professionalProfile.ExperienceLevel) {
                case 'ExperienceLevel_NoExperience':
                    score += 1;
                    break;
                case 'ExperienceLevel_LessThanOneYear':
                    score += 2;
                    break;
                case 'ExperienceLevel_BetweenOneAndThreeYears':
                    score += 4;
                    break;
                case 'ExperienceLevel_BetweenThreeAndFiveYears':
                    score += 6;
                    break;
                case 'ExperienceLevel_MoreThan5Years':
                    score += 10;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return score;
}
```

I don't know how I can do that kind of calculation using "aggregate". Any help or any other approach I could follow would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't want to do that. The `eval()` method for JavaScript execution is deprecated for all drivers and due for removal from the MongoDB server API soon. Read into that **"gone"**.  Everything you think you do in sever JavaScript execution you do "on the client" in the implementation language of your choice.

Comment: In short you want to do your calculation directly within the `select` instead. If the expression you want is not supported with LINQ, then you can always use `BsonDocument` construction with the "aggregate" method directly from the driver. But the "calculation" is the one thing missing from your question. So perhaps you should include what exactly that is.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn. I added more details about the calculation. Not sure if I explained properly what I need. I know it's quite complex and not sure if I'm following the right path.

Comment: The `switch/case` thing is not an issue for many of the people here to understand. It's more important to explain details such as the `professionalProfileRequirements`,`professionalProfile` arguments to the function and where they are actually supposed to come from in your current data. If you indicate which properties in classes used in the query actually represent those, then someone here can likely help. You need to give people as much detail as you have yourself when you want to get help here.

Comment: For an "immediate" point of guidance, there's not a "direct" correlation to `swich/case` which translates into LINQ supported by the driver. However "ternary" `if ? then : else` expressions are allowed.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll post another question showing my collections structure, the query I need and not mentioning the stored javascript at all. Thanks.